# Viewing SVG images on a Windows 7 64-bit machine

Tags: svg

I want to view SVG images on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I tried [Adobe's plug-in](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/), but it doesn't work.

Is there a freeware application which I can use to view SVG images on Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Firefox](http://www.getFirefox.com/), [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) or [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome).

Last time I checked, in the 32bit version of IE will run the Adobe plugin (but it is no longer supported).

Since you are on Windows 7, you can also download the [IE9 beta](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/) which does support SVG natively without a plugin now.

Comment: how about a standalone desktop app?

Comment: @iceman - not sure... but since I have at least 1 of the above browsers installed on every PC I have, I just use the browser.

Comment: If you wanted something not in a browser, you could use inkscape, which is actually an SVG editor.

Answer (score 3):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) has an SVG [plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm)
It's [shareware](http://www.cadsofttools.com/download/irfanviewplugins.zip)
You can also try [this one](http://www.antigrain.com/svg/index.html)

Comment: is the irfanview plugin supposed to work as an IE8 plugin or only in irfanview?
is the Svg viewer 3 supposed to work in x64 win7 at all?